# How do I use multiple character as single delimiter in awk?

Tags: shell, awk, gawk

I have a target file with delimiter as `"|^/"`.

Example :

```
123|^/qwe|^/po9076|^/env12|^/opti|^/546454
```

Now the requirement is to get the count of fields in each line.

I tired something like below, but it did not give correct result.

```
echo "123|^/qwe|^/po906|^/env12|^/opti|^/54644" | awk -F'|^/' '{print NF; exit}'
```

How to go about this issue?

**Note:** There can be either `|` or `^` or `/` inside a field value. So the delimiter should be **combination** of `|^/`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ echo "123|^/qwe|^/po906|^/env12|^/opti|^/54644" | awk -F'\\|\\^/' '{print NF; exit}'
6
```

`man awk` and `google regular expressions`.

Comment: This would probably be clearer as `awk -F"\\\\|\\\\^/"...` :)

Comment: I assume you're joking :-).

Answer (score 0):

You should use a brace expression (or character class) as field separator:

```
echo "123|^/qwe|^/po906|^/env12|^/opti|^/54644" | awk -F '[|^/]+' '{print NF; exit}'

6
```

Regex `[|^/]+` will make one or more of given characters inside `[...]` as input field separator.

Comment: My understanding of the question from OP's note is that the delimiter is literally the three-character sequence `|^/`. The use of the word "combination" makes it confusing, but OP seems to be saying the any of those characters can be in a field _value_, so all three are needed as the delimiter.

Comment: Yes, so imagine if one of the values was `abc|def`.  Wouldn't your FS count that as two fields?

Comment: Yes, of course this regex will treat it as two fields

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Anubhava, Ed's solution worked for me.

Comment: This answer didn't work because of your misleading requirement `There can be either | or ^ or / inside a field value`. What that sentence means **either of** those delimiters would split a field. On the other hand `'\\|\\^/'` will make it a 3 character length delimiter with string `|^/`